# How can i restore the default window size for Explorer and Notepad++

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, notepad++

So one day i went to play an old Visual Novel in fullscreen while accidentally leaving an Explorer and Notepad++ window open. when i closed the game both windows had been re-sized to the point that in Explorer i can just see one Large Icon.

I want to restore their original sizes which i don't know and ideally in a way which i can do with any program's window mode

NOTE: this is on a Windows 7 PC

Comment: I don't get it. Does it mean that both windows (Notepad++ and Windows Explorer) have become incredibly large? Can you at least see the bar at the top? If you double click on that, they will be maximized. Or are they very small?

Comment: @FabioTurati no the windows are very small and with how small they have gotten, in explore I can only just see 1 icon in the window with the view set to Large Icons

Comment: And what's preventing you from resizing the windows the normal way? I mean, if they are very small you can easily see the entire border all around them, so just click on any edge/corner and drag. Doesn't that work? Maybe a picture would help, can you show one?

Comment: @FabioTurati but manually resizing them won't get them back to the original default size which I have been using for years and as I said in the question I don't know these original sizes.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, now I've got it. Well then, I'm afraid I can't help you, and even worse, that there is no solution. Though I am not sure, I think Windows saves the last size of the window of each program, so that if you close it and then you reopen it, it can restore the last settings. In your case you'd need a history, saving previous sizes, which I'm pretty sure is not kept. For Notepad++ maybe you could uninstall and reinstall; for Windows Explorer I don't think you can. Maybe the initial sizes are written somewhere in the registry, but I'm skeptical. Anyway, I don't know. Sorry!